# How to use panda's 'apply' function with an imported function

Tags: python, pandas, function, module

I created a module inside of an anaconda environment with the structure:

"site-packages/mypackage/main.py"

I am trying to use a function from main.py (contains three functions) and when I apply it to a pandas dataframe column it returns all nulls.

This is the function and it works fine when it exists in my code (not imported- should turn "0 days 00:01:31.497000000" into 91).

```
def time_conversion(time):
"""Takes time differences and returns integer seconds or
takes 'minutes' and returns a string minute for a visualization 
axis"""
  if time is not np.nan:
      return int(pd.to_timedelta(str(time)).seconds)
  else:
      return np.nan
```

example this works:

```
df.col.apply(lambda x: time_conversion(x))

[91, 32, 5]
```

this returns nulls on same inputs:

```
from mypackage import main  #no issues with import it seems

df['col'].apply(lambda x: main.myfunc(x))

[NaN, NaN, NaN]
```

Comment: One suggestion: Try changing the file name from `main.py` to `somethingElse.py`

Comment: @meW maybe if `main` is conflicting with something else in the current namespace, if not, that shouldn't be the issue. That would also raise some sort of `Exception` I'd imagine, like `main has no attribute myfunc`

Comment: @C.Nivs Agree, that's why I called it a suggestion ;) for good python style guide.

Comment: @meW I don't disagree with the style suggestion

Comment: I think we need to see exactly what's going on in the `import`. Is there a `return`? Is there another `time_conversion` being imported under `main` that *doesn't* have a `return`?

Comment: Have you tested the imported function outside `pandas`'s `apply()`? Does it behave as expected?